# gcc inline assembly unreferenced input operand

Tags: gcc

I was going through the [gcc inline assembly documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) when i saw this example:

```
int test(char p[]) {
  int count;
  asm("repne scasb"
  : "=c" (count), "+D" (p)
  : "m" (*(const char (*)[]) p), "0" (-1), "a" (0));
}
```

I couldn't figure out the purpose of `"m" (*(const char (*)[]) p)`

[Looking at the generated code](https://godbolt.org/) with and without that shows that the only difference is the initialization of a register with the address of p which is not used by `repne scasb`. So it appears to be redundant. Is that statement useful in any other way?

Comment: It informs the compiler that the asm will be reading that memory.  This is important if the compiler is holding any values from there in registers, forcing them to get flushed to memory.  That godbolt link isn't doing scasb so I'm not sure what it's supposed to be showing.

Comment: sounds reasonable, thanks. for the godbolt, you can copy paste the function provided here to see its disassembly